# Dim range in previous sheet - run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to Dim two different ranges and I really don't understand where I'm going wrong here, I have no trouble in "`tdyRng`" but when I want to set "`ystRng`" I get "`Run-tim error 1004`". Why is this not possible to set a Range in a previous sheet? The sheet is a copy of the activesheet, so all cells are the same. I would appreciate any help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have the outer range object referencing an explicit sheet while the inner range object is referencing an implicit sheet. add ```ystSht.``` to the inner range.

Comment: Try using of `Set ystRng = ystSht.Range("C4", ystSht.Range("C4").End(xlDown))` instead of `Set ystRng = ystSht.Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown))`.  `Range("C4").End(xlDown)` reverences the active sheet...

Comment: I wouldn't use `ActiveSheet` and `Previous`.  What happens if the incorrect or first sheet is active when you run the code?  Are your sheets named with the date - if so you could use something like `Format(Date,"dd-mmm-yy")` to return the sheet name for todays date.  Also `tdySht`, `Cell`, and `tdyRange` are all `Variant` data types - you need to qualify each variable `Dim tdySht as Worksheet, ystSht as Worksheet`.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I guess i hit the wall yesterday and my head was full...I really appriciate the help, i know this have been covered before, but can be confusing looking at other exsamples where it all drowns in huge projects and lines of code.

I know I still have a lot to learn, and activesheet and previous is one of the places where there is a lot room for improvement, code can onlye be run with i click on a commandbutton, so its not the worst scenario tho.

I installed RubberDuck thanks to freeflow, i love it allready!